# Display still reset to minimum after restarting in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: xorg, brightness, backlight

I already follow these instructions provided in Ubuntu StackExchange and display is still reset to minimum after restarting.

1-

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_videoX/brightness
gksu gedit /etc/init/fixbrightness.conf
description "Sets brightness after graphics device is loaded"
start on graphics-device-added
task
exec /bin/echo BRIGHTNESS_VALUE > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_videoX/brightness
```

2-

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness`<br>  
gedit /etc/rc.local`
```

Add the line below before the last. Change the number 0 to the brightness level you want.

```
  echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
#I set 9 here.
```

3- Update Grub file, line no 11 in /etc/default/grub to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
update grub using the command
update-grub
```

4-

```
sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Add the following lines to this file:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

5-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/sysvinit-backlight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sysvinit-backlight
```

Im using intel video card for brightness. Backlight found at:

```
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue of display brightness reset to the minimum after restarting. Remove all configurations made, number 1, 2, 4, and 5 and only apply instruction number 3. However, it sets to maximum brightness every restart and changing of brightness level doesn't work. It's okay for me now, instead of having a minimum display brightness every time.